# Scroll window after timeout

Tags: jquery, scroll, settimeout, scrollto, window.location

I would like to be able to use jQuery's scrollTo plugin to animate the window scroll down to a div when Google directions are loaded. Could someone please help me convert the setTimeout line to jQuery and use scrollTo to animate the scroll? Here is the javascript that doesn't scroll:

```
      GEvent.addListener(gdir, 'load',  onGDirectionsLoad)

        function onGDirectionsLoad(){   
            setTimeout('eval(\'window.location = "#directions"\;\')', 500); 

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question.

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous function rather than `eval()`:

```
function onGDirectionsLoad() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.scrollTo("#directions", 1000);
  }, 500);
}
```

<sup>* Uses [Ariel Flesler's $.scrollTo()](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) jQuery Plugin.</sup>